# Notation for differentiable (but not necessarily $C^1$) functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, notation, mean-value-theorem

I was wondering whether there is a standard notation for the set of differentiable functions (but the derivative doesn't not need to be bounded, i.e. not necessarily $C^1$)

This question is in the context of the mean value theorem:

> f $\in C[a, b]$ and differentiable on (a, b) $\implies$ $\exists c \in (a, b)$ s.t. $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose you can use $D^1$.

Comment: I don't think there is a _standard_ notation, that is, a notation that lots of people would recognize without it being explained. But maybe in some mathematical milieu there is...

Comment: Of course, if you're writing it up for a document of some sort (e.g. homework or paper), there is no issue with simply saying "$D^1$ is defined to be all functions such that..." and so on. If there is no standard notation and it doesn't conflict with established ones, may as well make your own.

Comment: @zwim Thank you. Is that a common notation please? Because I only found very  few paper on Google using this notation.